# Displaying 3D models in Flash on the browser

Tags: flash, model, 3d, viewer

I have a bunch of digital 3d models (in whatever format, I can probably accommodate the conversion) and all I'm trying to do is to find a flash 3d viewer that dynamically gets a 3d model and then allows the user to do things like pan, zoom, and move around in the model. These are specifically models of units and properties, so presentation and smoothness is certainly required. The models are NOT going to be very detailed and heavy. They'll be approximate models with texturing plastered on top.

The only thing I've been able to find is Sophie3d, but as you can see in their demo page, it's extremely heavy, slow and laggy when rendering a room.

Any kind of license is ok, of course if it's open source I would gravitate towards that!

Thanks a lot guys,

Ali

Answer (score 3):

[Papervision3D](http://dev.papervision3d.org/) is an extremely popular 3d engine/library for ActionScript 3. It is possible to import many of the industry standard 3d formats into Papervision, including collada, 3DS, and more.

Comment: This 3D library is very outdated, the forum which is supposed to contain all important information was taken down. The examples don't even work.